# tail | gzip gives different file length than gzip after tail

Tags: pipe, gzip, tail

I want to gzip the last N bytes of a file. However, tail | gzip gives different output length than gzip after tail.

```
tail --bytes=1000 ./input > ./output.tmp
gzip -k output.tmp

tail --bytes=1000 ./input | gzip > ./output.gz

stat --format=%n:%s *

input         : 4843152
output.gz     : 449
output.tmp    : 1000
output.tmp.gz : 460
```

Why `tail` and then `gzip` gives 460 bytes but `tail | gzip` gives 449 bytes?

Comment: http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer <- random guess: compressing a file records the FNAME, compressing a stream does not?

Comment: yeah, that math checks out, putting as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer

If you compress a file, the original filename is recorded in the FNAME field.
If you compress a stream, there is no original file name.

That seems to account for the difference in your case.